# How to identify, use, and replace the Copperhead Bowden coupler?

Tags: bowden, ptfe-tube

After attempting to remove my Bowden tube for maintenance I have managed to break the coupler used to secure the Bowden tube in my Slice Engineering Copperhead heat sink. I'm having significant trouble identifying the proper name of and source for a replacement coupler. I've located others which seem to be similar in design but not the same size. I'm finding conflicting name and type information and am unsure which is correct. It's a small black plastic coupler with a blue ring clip used to secure it.

To prevent future issue I also would like to know the proper procedure for use... i.e. the methods for securing and removing the Bowden tube without damage.

Comment: Would you  add a Photo please

Answer (score 2):

It's an *embedded Bowden collet*. Also called a Bowden clip which is a much more vague and overloeaded term.

E3D (UK) and MicroSwiss (US) have their own branded versions but they're likely not made in house, they're prbably reselling what they buy in.

Youtubers appear to pronounce this Bowden colle**c**t which does not help.